# Drawing A triangle with SDL2 and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

I am trying to make a game in C++ and using SDL2 with OpenGL.
When I try to draw a simple triangle to the opengl context with GLEW nothing is showing up. I haven't used opengl before.
Here is my code:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <GL/gl.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include <iostream>
```

I have Fragment and Vertex shaders but StackOverflow said I had too much code and not enough details.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_STENCIL_SIZE, 8);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("GAME", 100, 100, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);

    printf("%u\n", vertexBuffer);

    float vertices[] = {
            0.0f, 0.5f,
            0.5f, -0.5f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f
    };
        GLuint vbo;
        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);

        glCompileShader(vertexShader);


        GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);

        glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

        GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);

        glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");

        glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

        GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
        glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);

        GLuint vao;
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);

    SDL_Event event;
    while(true)
    {
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) break;
        }

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
        glClearColor(0.2578125f,  0.52734375f,  0.95703125f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    }

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this with `g++ src/main.cpp glad/src/glad.c -I./glad/include -o main -lGL -lglfw -lGLEW -ldl -lSDL2 -ldl --std=c++14`

Answer (score 0):

The vertex specification is stored in the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). `glVertexAttribPointer` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray` set states in the currently bound VAO. So you have to create and bind the VAO **before** the vertex specification.

```cpp
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
```